# NSLocks in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

We use NSLock for locking in Objective C. I am porting a c plus plus code.
There they have used locks for critical section and mutex locks.
Is NSLock sufficient to lock critical section as well as mutex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that `NSLock` is sufficient, but if you think that you might have to lock while the lock is already locked (thereby causing a deadlock), you may want to look at `NSRecursiveLock`.

Comment: [[object getLock]lock]; and [[object getLock]unlock]; is sufficient.Isnt it.